# Drag & drop or click & select problems when CPU busy

Tags: windows, windows-10, cpu, mouse

**System:**
Desktop running Windows 10 22H2
AMD FX(tm)-4350 Quad-Core Processor
8 GB RAM 
AMD Radeon R7 200
Windows and drivers up to date. Full system malware scan returned negative.

**The Problem:**
While using the computer (ordinary, non-gaming use, e.g. browsing the internet, writing text, trying to move files), I occasionally have trouble using the mouse when keeping the left button pressed is required. Typically, this means problems selecting a block of text or dragging & dropping files from one window to the next. What happens is that the mouse button press is "lost", and the text isn't selected or the file isn't moved.

The problem appeared a couple of weeks or so ago. I don't recall making any drastic changes to the system or installing any new programs. I suspected a mouse problem, particularly since trying the mouse on another computer (also Windows 10, laptop) displayed the same behavior. I bought a new mouse, but the problem *persists*.

Baffled (since the problem existed with two different mice on two different computers), I started to look more into it and discovered a *correlation*: It seems it is far more likely for the problem to occur when the CPU is suddenly busy. I'm not entirely sure if certain processes seem more likely to trigger this, but at least Windows Update seems to be one of the culprits.

**Other Questions I Read:**
[Weird mouse problems. Accidental double-clicking, selection, drag-n-drop problems](https://superuser.com/questions/807761/weird-mouse-problems-accidental-double-clicking-selection-drag-n-drop-problem) 
[Drag and drop does not work (Windows 7, Outlook 2010, from inbox to )](https://superuser.com/questions/516254/drag-and-drop-does-not-work-windows-7-outlook-2010-from-inbox-to) 
[Why does "drag & drop" stop working after a while?](https://superuser.com/questions/29266/why-does-drag-drop-stop-working-after-a-while) 
But none seemed directly relevant.

**My question:**
Is there any kind of rationale in my thinking, is there any process that could indeed cause such a behavior (i.e. interfere with mouse actions)? I also noticed a process called "Service Host: Remote Procedure Call" is activated with drag & drop, if that's relevant in any way.

Comment: Open Windows Tools, Resource Monitor and let it run for 15 minutes or so when the system is busy as you describe. Look at both CPU and Disk to see if you can see what processes are causing the system to be busy.

Comment: You're stating *both* computers have the same issue: "the mouse on another computer (also Windows 10, laptop) displayed the same behavior. " As you imply, look for an update that has not completed. Perform a *full* shutdown, reboot, and check Windows Update CPL for any new or incomplete update. Also, use Task Manager and Resource Monitor, as @John states, to check CPU and I/O for hogs.

Comment: I don't see any incomplete Windows updates. Everything is reported as up to date (on the control panel). Even so (and even if I choose to "pause updates for 7 days"), the System Update process seems to be doing something (using ~15% of CPU) for a few minutes every hour or so. Perhaps it simply checks to see if there are any updates? In any case, the problem isn't _directly_ caused by Windows update itself. I've noticed the same mouse behavior when e.g. Firefox is doing something CPU-intensive. To me, it seems whatever process controls the mouse doesn't have high enough priority. Or...?